# Trim Cells in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying remove the spaces from excel cell.the code what i am using is as fallows:

```
    Dim cell As Range, areaToTrim As Range
    Set areaToTrim = Sheet1.Range("A1:D50")
    For Each cell In areaToTrim
        cell.Value = LTrim(cell.Value)
    Next cell
```

The error what i get is as fallows:
[image]

Kindly give me better idea to trim the leading and trailing spaces present in the cell.

Comment: I already test your code .. and it worked !

Comment: Yeah, I don't reproduce that error either.  More information perhaps?  Try your code in a new sub and/or workbook?

Comment: @all OK i will try it... :)

Answer (score 1):

This will trim the cells, both leading and trailing.

`lngCounter` gets the last row of data, `strRange` gets the active column and sets the rows 2 to lngCounter, i.e. the last row of data.

The code walks around each `Cell` in `strRange` and applies `Trim`. This cuts all of the spaces from the cell value.

```
Sub CutMe()

Dim lngCounter As Long
Dim rCell As Range
Dim strRange As String

lngCounter = Cells.Find("*", [A1], , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).row 
strRange = Chr(ActiveCell.Column + 64) & "2:" & Chr(ActiveCell.Column + 64) & lngCounter

For Each rCell In Range(strRange).Cells

    rCell.Value = Trim(rCell.Value)

Next rCell

End Sub
```